# my console.log() to firebase object is returning undefined yet not throwing any errors in the console

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I've been back and forth trying to learn how to get firebase up and running with angular 2.  I've gotten to a point where I'm not getting any errors, but my data still doesn't seem to be loading.  As I've found between angular-cli, angularfire and firebase there's tons of things you guys were doing in just August that are obsolete now so figuring that out the hard way has been a series of curve balls.  I've structured it as best as I can understand it so far and need help figuring out what the problem is.

This is the JSON I uploaded to firebase.

```
{
    "home_data" : {
        "bus_expand" : {
            "bus_image" : {
                "questions" : [
                    {
                    "question": "How do you feel about your current image?",
                    "id" : "exp-img-q1",
                    "name" : "exp-img-ques1",
                    "answers" : [
                        {
                        "answer" : "It's fine as is.",
                        "id" : "exp0101q"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "I want to make minor adjustments.",
                        "id" : "exp0102q"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "I want to change my image.",
                        "id" : "exp0103q"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "I've never wanted to use a particular image until now.",
                        "id" : "exp0104."
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                    "question": "To what degree?",
                    "id" : "exp-img-q2",
                    "name" : "exp-img-ques2",
                    "answers" : [
                        {
                        "answer" : "I want the same elements, just put together in a way that works better.",
                        "id" : "exp0201"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "I want to let go and do something new.",
                        "id" : "exp0202"
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "bus_tiers" : {
                "questions" : [
                    {
                    "question" : "Do you have multiple tiers of products, services, campaigns, etc. that need branding?",
                    "id" : "exp-tier-q",
                    "name" : "exp-ques3",
                    "answers" : [
                        {
                        "answer" : "Yes",
                        "id" : "exp0301"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "A couple, but not many",
                        "id" : "exp0302"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "No",
                        "id" : "exp0303"
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "bus_content" : {
                "questions": [
                    {
                    "question": "How do you manage building content for advertising and marketing?",
                    "id" : "exp-col-q",
                    "name" : "exp-ques4",
                    "answers" : [
                        {
                        "answer" : "I have enough Abode skills to put things togeather on my own.",
                        "id" : "exp0401"    
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "I use an app.",
                        "id" : "exp0402"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "I find an Artist when I need something.",
                        "id" : "exp0403"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "I have an inhouse Designer.",
                        "id" : "exp0404"
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "bus_location" : {
                "questions": [
                    {
                    "question": "Is your physical location open to the public?",
                    "id" : "exp-atmo-q2",
                    "name" : "exp-ques6",
                    "answers" : [
                        {
                        "answer" : "Yes",
                        "id" : "exp0501"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "No",
                        "id" : "exp0502"
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                    "question" : "Do you have a website?",
                    "id" : "exp-atmo-q2",
                    "name" : "exp-ques6",
                    "answers" : [
                        {
                        "answer" : "Yes",
                        "id" : "exp0601"
                        },
                        {
                        "answer" : "No",
                        "id" : "exp0602"
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

This is the service file for calling it up.

```
import { Injectable }                           from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable }    from 'angularfire2';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class FirebaseService{
    businessImage: FirebaseObjectObservable<bus_image>;

    constructor(private af:AngularFire){

    }

    getBusImg(){
        this.businessImage = this.af.database.object('/home_data/bus_expand/bus_image') as FirebaseObjectObservable<bus_image>

        return this.businessImage;
    }
}


    export interface answers {
        $key: string;
        id: string;
        answer: string;
    }

    export interface questions {
        $key: string;
        question: string;
        id: string;
        name: string;
        answers: answers[];
    }

    export interface bus_image {
        questions: questions[];
    }
```

My app component

```
import { Component, OnInit }                    from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable }    from 'angularfire2';

import { FirebaseService }                      from './services/database.service';

@Component({
    moduleId:       module.id,
    selector:       'app-root',
    templateUrl:    './app.component.html',
    styleUrls:      ['./app.component.css'],
    providers:      [ FirebaseService ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'app works!';

    businessImage: bus_image;

    constructor(private _firebaseService:FirebaseService){

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._firebaseService.getBusImg().subscribe(businessImage => {
            this.businessImage = businessImage;
        });

        console.log(this.businessImage);
    }


 }

export interface answers {
    $key: string;
    id: string;
    answer: string;
}

export interface questions {
    $key: string;
    question: string;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    answers: answers[];
}

export interface bus_image {
    questions: questions[];
}
```

This is the HTML template.

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>


<div *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <h1>{{questions.question}}</h1>
    <p *ngFor="let answer of answers">
        {{answers.answer}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Another thing confusing me about understanding how this works is the way we use the same name in lowercase and uppercase to keep everything simple.  When seeing something new trying to figure it out it can be hard to tell exactly which thing is being active where when they're all named the same thing in the same case, so I really can't tell which parts the data is coming or going through or referring to the local variable we're storing it in.  So a little help in that area would be appreciated as well.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, for one your `console.log` is happening synchronously with the subscribe method. Put it inside the subscribe callback handler and see what happens

Comment: THAT DID IT!!!!.... it still isn't binding to the template though.  I just realized I forgot to add that in the post so I just put it there.  Isn't that the way I need to do it?

Comment: What is `answers`? What is `questions`? Where is the `businessImage` binding in the template?

Comment: @echonx I just updated the post a second ago to show the template.

Comment: Not showing anything, is because you are trying to iterate through something that doesn't exist, i.e `questions`. You *ngFor to questions is actually: `let question of businessImage.home_data.bus_expand.bus_image.questions` But this won't work, as this is not an array. NgFor only supports arrays. Yours is an Object. So you have to access Object keys instead or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after a few days of poking around reading everything I can find I came up with this solution.

I changed instances `FirebaseListObservable` to `FirebaseObjectObservable`.

Then in `app.component` I changed the

```
businessImage: bus_image;
```

part to

```
businessImage: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
```

After that I changed my template to look like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let question of businessImage?.questions">
    <h1>{{question.question}}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let answer of question.answers">
            {{answer.answer}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

after that everything worked like a charm.  Thanks to everybody who had input, it definitely helped me figure out what I needed to look into in order to figure this out.